# How can you make your program sleep so that the GUI can catch up to what's happening?

Tags: java, swing, animation, user-interface

I'm making a snake game([for those who don't know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29)) where the snake is controlled by an AI using different algorithms to catch the food. The difference with the regular game is that the snake doesn't move unless a command has been sent by the AI.

My problem is that as soon as I run the AI, the AI creates a stack of commands to be executed to catch the food but my GUI just freezes; probably because it can't keep up with the amount of repaints that the move stacks cause. Through console logs, I can see that AI and the game logic is still running.

I tried to do `Thread.sleep()` after each move but I guess this just makes the entire program including the GUI sleep. I also have a `Timer` for my `paintComponent` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

How can you make your program sleep so that the GUI can catch up to what's happening?

EDIT:

Ok guys, I tried your solutions and it's still not working as it should. I don't really want to just dump the code here but I'm really lost. I have a timer that should repaint on a 140 millisecond interval(that's the value of DELAY), the commands are sent on a different thread which goes to sleep after each key press for 1000 milliseconds and I call repaint() after each call to move()... Here is relevant code(the original code without my modifications [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/)):

```
private void initGame() {

    dots = 5;

    for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
        x[z] = 50 - z * 10;
        y[z] = 50;
    }

    locateApple();
    for (int k = blockNb - 1; k > 0; k--) {

        locateBlock(k, apple_x, apple_y);
    }
    if (blocks) {
        locateBlock(0, apple_x, apple_y);
    }

    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();
    startAi();
}

// AI CONTROLLER
public void startAi() {
    Ai theAi = new Ai();
    String move = "";

    switch (ai) {
    case "BFS":

        move = theAi.bfs(this);
        break;
    }
    //AI returns a string where each char is a move command
    autoMove(move);

}

public void autoMove(String move) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        System.out.println(move);
        if (move != "#No") {

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < move.length(); j++) {

                        if (move.charAt(j) == 'l') {
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                        }

                        if (move.charAt(j) == 'r') {
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                        }

                        if (move.charAt(j) == 'u') {
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                        }

                        if (move.charAt(j) == 'd') {
                            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            thread.run();
        }
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    doDrawing(g);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    if (inGame) {

        g.drawImage(apple, apple_x, apple_y, this);

        for (int j = 0; j < blockNb; j++) {
            g.drawImage(block, block_x[j], block_y[j], this);
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            if (z == 0) {
                g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(ball, x[z], y[z], this);
            }
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

    } else {

        // gameOver(g);

    }
}



private void move() {

    for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
        x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
        y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
    }

    if (leftDirection) {
        x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (rightDirection) {
        x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (upDirection) {
        y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (downDirection) {
        y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

}




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (inGame) {
        repaint();
    }

}

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
            leftDirection = true;
            upDirection = false;
            downDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
            rightDirection = true;
            upDirection = false;
            downDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
            upDirection = true;
            rightDirection = false;
            leftDirection = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
            downDirection = true;
            rightDirection = false;
            leftDirection = false;
        }
        move();
        checkApple();
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Also, I just wanted to point out that I tried to move without relying on a robot but to no avail.

Comment: Have you considered adding a timer to your AI so that it doesn't add commands as often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:

Difference bettween Thread.sleep:

- When you use it in **main Thread**(the Thread which java use to run the program)

then your whole program just freeze for that reason.

- When you use A Thread for example(follow code)

  ```
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
     //do something...

      while(flag==false)
       Thread.sleep(a given time) //it need and try catch
      else
        //do your move
  });
  ```

  then only this Thread freeze (for a given time) or (Whatever you transform it to freeze).

In your case you can use a **flag** so every time a commant is hitten by user

the **flag is going true** and then again false to keep stopped the part of the

game you want but the **main Thread** your programms need to work still works
(if it is a window or anything...)

- Part 2:(Basic form of your Thread)(The flag i use must be seen by all Methods)(public or private)

  ```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
        flag=true;

   while(flag==true){

       if(move.equals("yes")){
          //your code

         move="no";
       }else
        Thread.sleep(20); //Sleep For a While(and then check again)
   }

  //That means that your Thread will run all over your game
  //until game over (when game over just do the flag=false;)
  //and The Thread will stop-exit

      }});
  ```

*About Repaint Method(Dont call the repaint method too fast)
Call it only when the player make a move(this is the time that the frame
need to be repainted[Ok if you have **.gif images** in your game just dont see this]

- Part 3:(When i made **a similar game** what i did)
  Before some months i tried a similar game.The basic idea was a player who must past a labirinth so....

  For each level i had one class like this...

  ```
   public abstarct class Level2(){

   //The game was into a panel like your.
   //Here i added .setFocusable and .addKeyListener to panel

    //Here it was an
    public void actionListener(){
        //The actionListener checked if the player found the door(for next level)


    //Here it was the repaint so every time something happened repaint()


     repaint();
    }//End of Action Listener


   //Use the paint or paintComponent what you need..
    public void paint[or paintComponent](Graphics g){

        //the 'squares' and the icons the had to be *repainted* again
    }



   //Here i had an extra class into this for the KeyListeners
   //And I added the KeyListener like your game(up,down,left,right)
   //I i said before i added this KeyListener to the panel
      private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
          //KeyPressed,Released...etc
      }
    }
  ```

**Thats the basic idea and for your game i think.**
The **Thread** it's an extra option i can't help more you must find the way...

Comment: I edited my original post with code that includes your suggestion but it's still not working correctly. Any idea? Did I implement it correctly?

Comment: and something more.. you don't need to call repaint again in KeyListeners it's called from actionListener

Comment: I figured it out; in my original code I was doing thread.run() but if you do that, when you call sleep it makes the whole thing sleep. What you need to do is new Thread(new Runnable(){}).start(). I'm not exactly sure why but that did it. Anyways, you post really helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a single "update" looped, from which your execute update commands and repaint request.

A simple approach would be to use a Swing `Timer`, which can trigger updates to a listener at regular intervals.  It has the benefit of been triggered within the context of the EDT making it safe to update the UI from within.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

A more complex approach would be to use a `Thread`, which contained some kind of loop.  This would perform the required updates and schedule repaint, but you'd need to insert `Thread.sleep` in to allow time for the updates to occur at a regular bases.  The problem with this is you will need to synchronise your updates so that you don't update the model while painting is occurring as well synchronise you updates to the UI with the EDT

Comment: The code I based my code on already implemented a Timer and I barely modified it. I've added relevant code of my implementation in my post and also linked the original code if you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of game scheduler loop and an understanding of how it works.

Here is some example code for java swing:

http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/swing/swingTimers

Another way to simplify things along with the scheduler is to make your game turn based at first. That is when the player moves 1turn (ie input) the game does all its processing and blocks on user input till the processing is done (ie single loop).

Comment: A Timer was already implemented. As for being turn based, I've tried to make it "turn based ish" by running the commands on a separate thread and making it sleep for 2000 milliseconds after each commands sent. This is still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your game AI outputs a new move, you need to call paint, but you also need to wait for whatever event is called when the painting is done before you output your next move, and you may want to wait like a second longer or something, play around with it

pseudo code

```
def fun 0 // entry point for program
  // hook paint done event to func 1
  call fun 2

def fun 1 // event handler method for when painting done
  call fun 2

def fun 2 // function that does AI work
  // do game logic
  // call paint
```